# Text 'listens' to float element below it, not the one on the same line

Tags: html, css, css-float

In Coda, my text float divs work perfectly. The text and the divs are both 1 em:
[image: Coda]

However, once I go to look at this same site in Chrome, the text now listens to the div below it, and as you can see the text is all on one line:
[image: Chrome]

What's wrong here? HTML/CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/u773M/2/

Comment: In my chrome it work fine. like your first row of pic.

Comment: That is really annoying. What version of Chrome are you on? (I'm on 22.0.1229.79)

Comment: 18.0.1025.162 m sorry for the delay.

Comment: I will updated my Chrome and then play with it. I'll keep you advise.

Comment: Can't telle sorry, Look likes it is a Chrome bug, as it was working on previous version.

Answer (score 0):

The size of your font is currently too big. Set a smaller font size on the anchor (not the list item, as that will change the size of your steps) and add set the anchor to display: block.

Without the proper space for the letters to spread out, they are just getting cut off and not rendering correctly.

Comment: If this: `li a {font-size:.5em;}` is the code you are suggesting, it doesn't work. (http://jsfiddle.net/u773M/5/) Please verify your solution using the jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry, I did verify this in the fiddle, but forgot to mention one other change. If you set the anchor to display: block and lower the font size, this should work correctly. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Giving widths to the text area or max-width (newer browsers) and either floating or displaying these will help with cross browser implementation - I have had similar issues before and you will find ie7 likes widths on text to be set dependant on the mark-up that surrounds.